# I'm installation magento 2 (Magento-CE-2.0.2) on local server

Tags: magento2

i mean on cpanel but facing this error, i did everything according to magento 2 installation requirement but at the end i don't know how to solve this error.

Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Comment: Please check the File and Folder Permissions.

Comment: Where is the error BTW?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below extensions are enabled in your server or local server:

Required PHP extensions:

- PDO/MySQL
- mbstring
- mcrypt
- mhash
- simplexml
- curl
- gd2
- ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
- soap

And also share the screenshot what exact error your facing.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: Your welcome @PratikMehta